# Data in child component is not updating

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that is pass the id of a category. But the data in the child component is loaded only once, when the data is passed the first time from parent to child.

If try to pass a different value, the `load()` function in the child component will not complete the request.

**parent.ts:**

```
  selectedCategory = '';

  onChange(event: any): void {
    this.selectedCategory = event.target.value;
  }
```

**parent.html:**

```
<select class="show-category form-control form-control-sm mb-4" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" 
     (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id" >
        {{category.categoryName}}
    </option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="selectedCategory">
    <app-child [isCategory]="selectedCategory"></app-child>
</div>
```

**child.ts:**

```
dataSource!: any;
@Input() isCategory!: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.load();
}

load() {
this.childService.getCategories(this.isCategory).subscribe((data) => {
    this.dataSource = data.data
  }, error => {})
}
```

**child.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataSource">
    {{data.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: On child component use ngOnChange instead of ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your category id to the route

e.g:
route module

```
{ path: 'categories/:id', component: CategoriesComponent }
```

then get it using snapshot

```
id: any
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
//using snapshot
this.id= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
```

Comment: This method does not suit me

Comment: try 'EventEmitter' it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set function for the input in the child:

```
private _isCategory: string;

@Input()
set isCategory(value){
    this._isCategory = value;
    this.load();
}
    
load() {
  this.childService.getCategories(this._isCategory).subscribe((data) => {
    this.dataSource = data.data
  }, error => {})
}
```

Or use the OnChanges component lifecycle

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input()
    private isCategory: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      if (changes.isCategory.currentValue){
        this.load();
      }
     }
}
```